# How to efficiently insert 100k+ rows into SQL database with Python

Tags: python, sql, performance, pyodbc

Using ODBC driver 18 for Windows, latest Python and pyodbc versions. SQL server is in Azure. Running the script from an Azure Function APP.

I have a script that executes the following steps:

1. Makes an API call, transforms the data as needed, saves each row with its column data as a list in a list (thereby making a list of lists).
2. Connects to a database, and inserts the list into its corresponding table (in the example below, 50k lists get inserted into the database at once).

As an example, one of the API calls returns 50k rows, with 46 columns each:

[image: row example]

This is the function that inserts the data into the table:

[image: insert function]

And this is the function that returns the string on where to insert the data (this is not important but I put it as reference):

[image: insertion string function]

All this code works fine. However, it seems to me it could be better. Especially for some of the other APIs that return 100k or even more rows to be inserted.

What would be the proper way of going about this? Currently, inserting 100k rows takes about 4-5 minutes, for example.

I haven't tried anything else since I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to working with databases in this way.

Comment: Please read more about bulk inserts https://www.sqlnethub.com/blog/how-to-run-the-sql-server-bulk-insert-command-from-within-a-python-program/

Comment: The quickest way is to use the database's bulk import tools or APIs. Executing INSERTs one by one is the slowest way possible. Which database are you using? Some databases have client-side bulk copy mechanisms. In other cases you can write an INSERT statement with *multiple* rows. That's the case with both MySQL and SQL Server for example. Instead of 100K INSERTs you could execute 1000 or 100

Comment: Another important problem with this code is SQL injection. What if one of the fields contains `'` or `,`? Or `'); DROP TABLE Users; #`  ? String interpolation both unsafe and *slower* than parameterized queries

Comment: @JamalAlkelani that blog post is specific to SQL Server and imports files accessible from the server. You'd have to save the data to a CSV file that's accessible from the server first. Which is *not* a bad idea - instead of keeping all rows in memory, write them out to a CSV directly and finally import the file

Comment: @Adehmar no matter the database one of the simplest and fastest options would be to save the data to a CSV file in a location that's accessible from the server, then use the server's `BULK INSERT` or `COPY` commands to bulk import the data. Instead of keeping all rows in a list you can append them to the CSV file as you create them, thus saving the RAM used for all those 100K rows

Comment: Azure SQL or SQL Server on an Azure VM? In [SQL Server 2017 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver16) BULK INSERT can accept the path to an Azure Blob Storage file. Writing to blob storage is more expensive than writing to disk though, so appending individual rows isn't the best option.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Azure SQL.